# Creating of segments overlap each other or they are separate, when we don't use any explicit instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, segment, memory-segmentation

In very simple assembly language programming, everyone may know the below
given lines:

```
cli
xor ax,ax
mov ss,ax
mov sp,7c00h
push ss
pop es
```

my very simple question is that, when in line number 3 we write mov ss,ax,
then value "0000" will move in the stack segment register ss. My problem is
in understanding that when we use two instructions "push ss" and "pop es".
then whether two segments ss and es will be created and start at the same
memory location starting at address "0000" (and thus overlap each other) or
two separate segments will be created containing the values "0000" (absolute
value) at their very first location. If the later condition satisfies then
will ss and es be created automatically (because we did not used any
instruction for creating the segments `SS` or `ES` using instructions like:)

```
stack segment stack1
end stack1

extra segment extra1
end extra1

assume stack:stack1 
extra:extra1
```

Comment: Moving a value into a segment register does not `create` a segment. It just sets the register pointing to a specific block of memory. If SS and ES have the same value then they are both pointing to the same block of memory.

Comment: Recall that in real mode, the values of segment registers are just added to the effective address to form a linear address in the form `linear_address = segment * 16 + effective_address`.  Nothing “creates” or “destroys” segments.  You can only do that in protected mode, where the mechanism is quite different.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your code, both `SS` and `ES` overlap each other and are pointing at the same segment. It's important to remember that a *segment* and a *segment register*, while related, are not the same. A "segment" is memory, and a segment register's value is part of a pointer to the corresponding segment.

It's very common to point two segment registers to the same segment of memory. Nothing new is created, they're just both looking at the same portion of memory.

```
.data

myString db "Hello",0
myBuffer db 0,0,0,0,0,0

.code

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax

mov si,offset myString
mov di,offset myBuffer

mov cx,6
rep movsb ;copy myString to myBuffer

mov ax,4C00h
int 21h   ;exit back to DOS
```